# how to process files inside a zip file

Tags: python

I have a zip file containing multiple files. I unzipped it and using one of the files to write the lines I wanted(cleansing data, calculation). Now I wonder how can I create a loop to apply my lines to all the files in the zip file?

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import string
from collections import Counter

punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
stopwords = ['a', 'an', 'the', 'that', 'these', 'those', 'of', 'to', 'i', 'you'
             'your', 'yours', 'he', 'she', 'they', 'me','him', 'her', 'them',
             'his', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'at', 'dont', 'its']

with ZipFile('articles.zip', 'r') as zip:
    with zip.open('articles/document0001.txt') as file:
        file_text = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        words = file_text.split()
        table = str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)
        decode_file = [w.translate(table) for w in words]
        more3_file = [f for f in decode_file if len(f) > 3]
        lower_file = [each_string.lower() for each_string in more3_file]
        new = []
        for i in range(len(lower_file) - 1, -1, -1):
            if lower_file[i] not in stopwords:
                new.append(lower_file[i])
        counts = Counter(lower_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `namelist` method to extract all the filenames inside the zip file.

```
with ZipFile('articles.zip', 'r') as zip:
    for filename in zip.namelist()[1:]:
        with zip.open(filename) as file:
            file_text = file.read().decode('utf-8')
            # rest of the code
```

The first element in `namelist`'s output is the directory itself, `articles` in your case. We have to skip that, that's why iterating from second element onwards - `zip.namelist()[1:]`

Comment: Thank you it worked! can I save the count file as csv?

Comment: Yeah, sure. `counts` is essentially a dictionary. `counts.items()` can be inserted as rows into the csv file. Such a csv file will have two columns, first column is the word and second column its frequency of occurrence.